# Trying to register a user from another controller other than AccountController gives an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Totally messed up my last question so posting a new one.

MyTestController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(MyTestViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                AccountController ac = new AccountController();

                var user = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = viewModel.Email
                };
                var result = await ac.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, viewModel.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await ac.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ac.AddErrors(result);
                }
```

The `SignInAsync` method in `AccountController` (changed this from `private` to `public`):

```
    public async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

While trying to register the user it gives me the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 411:            get
Line 412:            {
Line 413:                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
Line 414:            }
Line 415:        }
```

Those lines in `AccountController`:

```
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
```

Everything in the `AccountController` is default MVC 5 app stuff.

It is not possible to call these methods from another controller, like in my example above?

And why am I getting a `NullReferenceException` on line 413?

Comment: not sure what your account controller looks like or your Owin context set is like But I'm betting that account is setting up something behind the scenes that you don't know about, are there attributes or typeof(AccountController) or anything that would lead you to where the set up is happening. maybe a find all on AccountController may help

Answer (score 3):

Calling a Controller method from another Controller is difficult because of properties like the HttpContext which need to be properly initialized. This is usually done by the MVC framework which creates the controller using a ControllerFactory and at some point during this process the protected method Initialize is called on the controller which ensures that the HttpContext property is set.
This is why you get the exception on line 413, because the Initialize method hasn't been called on the controller you created using the new operator.

I think it would be easier to refactor out the functionality you want to share.
E.g. if both AccountController and your MyTestController holds a reference to something like this

```
public class AccountManager
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    public HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; private set; }

    public AccountManager()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public void Initialize(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        HttpContext = context;
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    public async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
}
```

You would then modify the `AccountController` like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new AccountManager())
    {
    }

    public AccountController(AccountManager accountManager)
    {
        AccountManager = accountManager;
    }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        AccountManager.Initialize(this.HttpContext);
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager 
    {
        get
        {
            return AccountManager.UserManager;
        }

    }

    public AccountManager AccountManager { get; private set; }
```

And your MyTestController would be like this:

```
public class MyTestController : Controller
{
    public MyTestController ()
        : this(new AccountManager())
    {
    }

    public MyTestController (AccountManager accountManager)
    {
        AccountManager = accountManager;
    }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        AccountManager.Initialize(this.HttpContext);
    }

    public AccountManager AccountManager { get; private set; }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(MyTestViewModel viewModel)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {  
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = viewModel.Email
            };
            var result = await AccountManager.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, viewModel.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await AccountManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result); //don't want to share this a it updates ModelState which belongs to the controller.
            }
```

**Update:**

Had to make som minor changes:

I had to change the UserManager property since the Dispose method uses the setter method:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
{
    get { return AccountManager.UserManager; }

    private set { _userManager = value; }
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && UserManager != null)
    {
        UserManager.Dispose();
        UserManager = null;
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

I had to add the AddErrors method to MyTestController (as you pointed out that we don't want to share that method):

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
{
    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
    }
}
```

I re-added this line to the AccountManager property in the AccountManager class (not really related to the question but I had it in my project)

```
UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```

Comment: Edited your post since this seems to be working and I added some minor changes in the update paragraph since I want this to be the one and final answer. Perhaps I'm doing this the stupid way in that case please let me know and I'll fix whatever needs to be fixed. Also I really appreciate your time and effort. Thanks a bunch! One last thing though: I would really like to learn more about all this stuff in your post. Overriding the Initialize method, the two constructors, the HttpContext classes etc. Is there some good resources on the interweb you could maybe share with us? Thanks again!

Comment: Also this line UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false }; couldnt get stackoverflow to parse it correctly. Bug?

Comment: These lines of code: protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) { base.Initialize(requestContext); AccountManager.Initialize(this.HttpContext); } Why can't we use requestContext.HttpContext instead of this.HttpContext for this line of code: AccountManager.Initialize(this.HttpContext);?

Comment: @PussInBoots Hi, I am struggling with this same problem as you were. thanks a lot for this informative answer but I am getting the same exception on this method AccountManager.Initialize(this.HttpContext); on my TestController class. can you please suggest me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me it working like a charm after setting the current ControllerContext to AccountControllerContext. Not sure if there are any drawbacks with this approach.

```
//This is employee controller class
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EmployeeId,FirstName,LastName,DOJ,DOB,Address,City,State,Mobile,Landline,ReportsTo,Salary")] Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AccountController accountController = new AccountController();
            accountController.ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext;
            //accountController.UserManager;
            var userId = accountController.RegisterAccount(new RegisterViewModel { Email = "temp@temp.com", Password = "Pravallika!23" });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                employee.UserId = userId;                    
                employee.CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }                
        }

//customized method in AccountController
    public string RegisterAccount(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };                
            IdentityResult result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
            //to add roles
            //UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return user.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed
        return null;
    }
```